# Marginal cost of window (framing) while in design phase

Tags: windows, framing, design

I've drawn up my sketch of floor plan I'll take to a house designer, but haven't added any windows yet. I'd like to have as much detail added to save designer time, but since I'm on a budget, I need help understanding what framing a window costs.

If I add a window here or there what does the extra framing cost, compared to a blank wall? Assume they're the load bearing exterior 2*6 walls, and like 4'*4' in size.[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, any answer would have to be some flavor of "it depends," and as such is probably off-topic here.

Comment: Is the smiley face intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where I live, 4x4 windows cost about $600 and another $300 for framing, header, etc. Trim around the opening varies from $100 - $200, depending on type of trim, stain or paint, etc.

Framing is not what is expensive in a house. It’s the finishes.

BTW, an “egress window” is required by Building Code in all bedrooms AND sleeping areas. It needs to open a certain amount and can’t be more than 42” - 44” or something like that off the floor. Check with Building Codes in your area.

Comment: It sounds like every time I add a window to the sketch it's $1000 extra. I can live with that rules of thumb. I'll let designer worry about codes